# Fetching those models whose polymorphic owner model has not been deleted

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a polymorphic relationship between `Post`, `Video` & `Comment`. A comment can either belong to a `Post` or a `Video` (just like the official documentation's example). The problem is, `Post` and `Video` are soft deletable. So how can I fetch those comments whose `Post` or `Video` has not been deleted. (i.e.: `commentable != null`). I tried `whereHas` but it didn't affect the query at all:

```
Comment::whereHas('commentable')->count();
```

returns the same number as this:

```
Comment::count();
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson 5.5.35

Answer (score 0):

`whereHas()` doesn't work with `MorphTo` relationships:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5429
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18523